# Avoiding misuse of "leading term". How to make it rigorous?

Tags: asymptotics, distribution-tails

I've seen several papers on heavy-tail analysis use "leading term" to refer to something which is a factor, not a term. For instance, if we've determined the asymptotics of a tail function to be
\begin{equation}
P(X>x)\sim\frac{1}{\log x}\cdot x^{-\log x} \quad\text{as }x\to\infty,
\end{equation}
they'll say that the "leading term" is $x^{-\log x}$. I get that $x^{-\log x}$ decays faster than $\frac{1}{\log x}$, so in a way it "contributes" more to the leading order behavior. Indeed, in the image below, we see that the graph of $\frac{1}{\log x}\cdot x^{-\log x}$ is much closer to $x^{-\log x}$ than to $\frac{1}{\log x}$. But what is the most sensible mathematical way of stating this? I.e. the fact that for large $x$, it's the leading factor that determines the asymptotic behavior, and the slower-decaying factor is "negligible" in some sense?

[image]

Comment: Something like $-\log(P(X > x))$ is $\Theta((\log x)^2)$? (it's not clear to me what type of result you're wanting)

Comment: There is $P = o(x ^ {-log x})$ as $x \to \infty$. Is this something like what you are referring to?

Comment: @Peter You're right, we have $P=o(x^{-\log x})$, but it's equally true that $P=o(1/\log x)$. So that doesn't explain why $x^{-\log x}$ is the leading term while $1/\log x$ is negligible somehow.

Comment: When you have a product of two reasonably simple factors which both converge to $0$, it would make sense to simplify it by comparing it to the one that converges faster. I can't explain why the word *term* is used instead of *factor* though.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting at: if we want to compare $P(x)$ to some other expression, let's say $g(x)$, and determine which one decays faster, it's sufficient to compare $g(x)$ to the leading term of $P(x)$, i.e. $x^{-\log x}$. We don't need to consider $1/\log x$ unless the leading terms of $g$ and $P$ are completely identical.